# Reading an array into another array and storing all objects into a list using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a model (user) which contains an array (discontinued items). IDs are stored within this array, all of which belong to a specific item model. Now I would like to list all users where this array is not empty and then, in the same step, read out all articles from this array using their ID. Unfortunately, I can't do this because I get "undefinded" in the console when I print. What is that? Thank you very much

```
export const AlleUserMitArtikel = async (req, res) => {
try {
const alleUser = await User.find({
  eingestellteArtikel: { $exists: true, $not: { $size: 0 } },
});

const liste = await Promise.all(
  alleUser.map(async (user) => {
    console.log(user); //Displays the correct object in the console, see below
    user.eingestellteArtikel.map(async (id) => {
      console.log(id); //Displays the correct ID, see Error section first two entries
      return await Artikel.find({ _id: id });
    });
  })
);
console.log(liste); //Displays undefined

res.status(200).json(alleUser);
} catch (error) {
 console.log(error);
 }
};
```

USER MODEL:

```
  {
 _id: new ObjectId("630f36f0295ec768e2072c10"),
 eingestellteArtikel: [ '630fe7caabfdf4387030a723', '63105cbedae68f22984ba434' ],
 createdAt: 2022-08-31T10:24:48.845Z,
 updatedAt: 2022-09-01T07:18:22.044Z,
 __v: 0,
  }
```

Undefined message:

> 630fe7caabfdf4387030a723
>
> 63105cbedae68f22984ba434
>
> [ undefined, undefined ]

Comment: Please provide some documents for both collections and your requested results for them

Comment: I'm not completely clear about the output you want, but I'm pretty confident all this logic can be done by the MongoDB server using `"$lookup"`.